# Chrome localhost response is very slow

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, localhost

I'm developing web server in mac osx. But when I request some ajax call, it's reponse time is very slow.

- Front server response : 

  `proxy to ApiServer
  ::1 - GET /ajax/best?page=5&order=hot&categoryValue&listType HTTP/1.1 200 - - 90.301 ms`
- API server response : 

  `::ffff:127.0.0.1 - GET /ajax/best?page=5&order=hot&categoryValue&listType HTTP/1.1 200 - - 82.590 ms`

It takes around 90 ms. But in chrome profile, XHR response takes more than 3 sec.
[image]

I request same ajax call in safari, it just takes **96ms**.

Here is my /etc/hosts

  `127.0.0.1 localhost
  255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
  ::1 localhost
  fe80::1%lo0 localhost`

What is problem in chrome?? I can't find what makes the request slow...